# Navigate/Swipe between articles in section using table view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a simple app which have table view controller containing few articles in sections, e.g. 3 articles in Sports section:
[image]

When I open a specific article in this section I want to be able to swipe left in order to move to the next article in section,
How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you will need to create

- a global storage for your articles, let's call it `articles`.
  According to `articles` you can populate your `tableView`.
- add a swipe gesture recognizer to your opened article page
- whenever you swipes from right to left, you push a new viewcontroller to your navigation stack, and setup this viewcontroller with the next item of `articles`.

Comment: Thanks, I have a global articles var, how can I push a new viewcontroller?

Comment: @DorCohen if there is navigation controller yet in your app, you should embed your tableview controller in it, and after that you should just use the **pushViewController:animated:** method to push your viewcontroller to the navigation stack.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me.

- I have a tableview displaying many cells of data
- Tap on a cell to segue to a detail view controller showing more data from the cell
- Swipe left to view effectively refresh the detail view controller with data from the next cell
- In my app, the data is in a singleton so any view can go retrieve that data from the data structure in the singleton. FYI: The data structure is populated from a API call that returns a JSON that is decoded into the data structure.

When a swipe left is detected, handleTap is called.  The productNumberInPage increments.  That is the index that looks up the data from the NetworkManager singleton.  That is not required, just my implementation.

After the productNumberInPage is incremented, setupViews is called.  That results in page being refresh with new data.  You could also add an animation here.

To implement, add a gesture recognizer into your detail view controller that calls a setupViews function in the detail view controller.

```
class ProductDetailVC: UIViewController {

  // MARK: - Variables
  var productNumberInPage = 0

  // MARK: - IBOutlets
  @IBOutlet weak var productNameLabel: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var reviewRatingLabel: CosmosView!
  @IBOutlet weak var reviewCountLabel: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var productImage: UIImageView!
  @IBOutlet weak var priceLabel: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var freeShippingLabel: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var inStockLabel: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var shortDescription: UITextView!
  @IBOutlet weak var longDescription: UITextView!
  @IBOutlet weak var contentView: UIView!

  // MARK: - Functions
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let recognizer: UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSwipe(recognizer:)))
    recognizer.direction = .left
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
    setUpView()
  }

  func setUpView() {
    guard let products = NetworkManager.instance.allProducts[pageWithTV].products else { return }
    productNameLabel.text = products[productNumberInPage].productName ?? "N/A"
    self.reviewRatingLabel.rating = products[productNumberInPage].reviewRating ?? 0
    reviewCountLabel.text = "\(products[productNumberInPage].reviewCount ?? 0)"
    priceLabel.text = products[productNumberInPage].price ?? "N/A"

    shortDescription.text = (products[productNumberInPage].shortDescription ?? "Not available.").html2String
    longDescription.text = (products[productNumberInPage].longDescription ?? "Not available.").html2String

    if let inStock = products[productNumberInPage].inStock, inStock {
        inStockLabel.text = IN_STOCK
        inStockLabel.textColor = ColorPalette.Green.Medium
    } else {
        inStockLabel.text = OUT_OF_STOCK
        inStockLabel.textColor = ColorPalette.Red.Medium
        freeShippingLabel.textColor = ColorPalette.White.Medium
    }

    image from a URL
    let image = UIImage(named: LOADING_IMAGE)
    guard let url = products[productNumberInPage].productImage else { return }
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.productImage.kf.setImage(with: url, placeholder: image)
    }
  }


  @objc func handleSwipe(recognizer : UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
        guard productNumberInPage != (PAGE_SIZE - 1) else {
            print("Sorry out of products on this page. Go back to list view")
            return
        }
        productNumberInPage += 1
        setUpView()
    }
}
```