# Reload regular view controller (swift)

Tags: swift

My view controller display the view depends on an array. the object of the array may be removed according to user interaction. So i have to reload the view controller once the user delete data in the array. is there any way to reload the regular view controller?

Comment: possible [duplication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31207783/reloading-a-view-controller-swift)

Comment: there is no solution

Answer (score 0):

You should design the view according to the array in one method and call it every time the array changes.

```
private func setupView() {
   ...
   self.setNeedsLayout()
}

private func deleteObject() {
   myArray.removeAtIndex(2)
   self.setupView()
}
```